# Definition: vector or point belonging to an area

Tags: definition, vectors, area

This is an applied problem, which I try to define mathematically. I have two vehicles, vehicle 1 is defined by the area, dependent on length $L$ and width $W$ of the vehicle, according to: $\begin{bmatrix}
       -\frac{L}{2}    \\[0.3em]
       -\frac{W}{2} 
     \end{bmatrix}  
     \leq A_{E} \leq
\begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{L}{2} \\[0.3em]
       \frac{W}{2}
     \end{bmatrix}   $

Globally, the middle point of this vehicle is positioned in point $E$, and the middle point on vehicle 2 is positioned in the global cartesian point $P$.

If we think about the problem as if everything is seen from vehicle 1's view, the length of vehicle 1 is aligned with the x-axis in the coordinate system. Vehicle 2 has an area made up of:
$\begin{bmatrix} 
       \mu_Px-\frac{\bar{L}}{2}    \\[0.3em]
       \mu_Py-\frac{\bar{W}}{2} 
     \end{bmatrix}  
     \leq A_P \leq
\begin{bmatrix}
       \mu_Px+\frac{\bar{L}}{2} \\[0.3em]
       \mu_Py+\frac{\bar{W}}{2}
     \end{bmatrix}      $

where $\mu_Px$ and $\mu_Py$ are the mean of the x- and y coordinate of the measured position P.

In theory an infinite number of points are spread out over vehicle 2's area, but in reality we use N points. These points are rotated according to both vehicles headings. In the deterministic case we want to check whether any of the points of vehicle 2 is inside the (global) area of vehicle 1. This means that we need to find the difference between each point and evaluate if it is located in the bounding box $A_E$. For simplicity, consider N to be 1 and that this point is rotated according to the headings and denoted $P1$. The distance (vector?) between these points are calculated as:

$\overrightarrow{EP1} = [P1_x-E_x,P1_y-E_y]$

What I now want to check is if there is a risk of collision between the two vehicles (these two points, the problem is simplified) by evaluating the following:

$ P_{collision} =
  \begin{cases}
    1       & \quad \text{if } \; \overrightarrow{EP1} \in A_{E}\\
    0  & \quad \text{otherwise }
  \end{cases}
  $

for example a collision risk will be present if E = (L/2,W/2) and P1 = (L/4,W/4)=>$\overrightarrow{EP1}=(L/4,w/4)$ which is inside $A_E$.

**Now my question is how you should write and refere to this correctly, if it is correct to say that a vector ($\overrightarrow{EP1}$) belongs to an area, or if this should be referred to in some other way (maybe we should ask if a point belongs to the area?).**

---

Here is some additional information than maybe can be of help, or only be confusing...

The measured and predicted positions of both vehicles are the global cartesian middle point of each vehicle and can be seen as two bivariate variables, Vehicle 1: $E\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu_E},\boldsymbol{\Sigma_E})$

and vehicle 2: $P\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu_P},\boldsymbol{\Sigma_P})$

The rotated point on vehicle 2 is also considered a bivariate variable denoted: $P_1\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu_{P_1}},\boldsymbol{\Sigma_P})$

By using linear combination of the variables similarly to the deterministic equation the following distribution can be formulated:
$D\sim\mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu_{P_1}}-\boldsymbol{\mu_E},\boldsymbol{\Sigma_{E}}+\boldsymbol{\Sigma_P})$

with the use of the joint cumulative distribution can the probability of collision be calculated as,
$ P=\iint\limits_{A_E} D\, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y = \int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2}\int\limits_{-w/2}^{w/2} D\, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y $

Comment: I don't quite understand how you bound a scalar area by vectors. If you want to check for collisions in practice, you would detect edges and check for intersections, or draw bounding boxes around vehicles. Also , $EP$ is the distance vector, so what you in fact do is trace a sphere with radius $EP$ around your vehicle. Another setup would be to check the maximum distance from the center of a vehicle a point on it's perimeter ($r_i$), trace two such spheres (1/vehicle) and then giving a collision whenever $EP<r_1+r_2$.

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze I simplified the problem to not make it too complex. Think about one vehicle as the area defined above, the other vehicle's area is made up my an infinite number of points covering its area (rotated according to both vehicles heading). Theoretically, a collision could then be said to be present when at least one of these points are positioned inside the other vehicles area. The reason for this definition is that, later, we want to get a probability of collision and not only a true or false value.

Comment: OK, but "the other vehicle's area is made up by an infinite number of points covering its area"  is the definition of an area. From this I assume that your area is a vector $A = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \times 3$, a vector of infinitely many points (which you should state in your question, since by default area is a scalar). Assuming this setup, your idea could work in theory, but would require simplifications in case you want to run a simulation. Also, how would you plan to tell if a point is in an "area" or not? Just curious.

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze Sorry, I'm not so good in definitions and mathematical expressions and that's what I want to get help with. Why do you assume that the area is a vector or dimension 3 (because that's what the "3" stands for, isn't it?). Yes, this is in theory... it is implemented in simulations with a finite number of points, so I know my idea but I haven't described it for you since I didn't think that it was necessary. But I've tried to put more details now, hope that it helps.

Comment: Johanson I tried to graph your experiment / simulation, here it is. http://s18.postimg.org/hl85mex9l/export.png Please correct if I messed up anything. I understand what you want to do better now (thanks for the details). Since you mentionned "bounding box", I assume what you are doing is actually delimiting an area, populating it with points with gaussian distribution, taking differences with their homologs in the other vehicle and computing some probabilities. Am I right?

Comment: And for your question of belonging to an area, I believe you can't quite talk about vectors belonging to somewhere, since they can be freely moved. In your case, your vector $EP1$ is the distance between "centers of mass" and it simply shows how far apart your points are. What you can test is, as you said it, whether a point belongs to an area, i.e. whether it is within some bounding curve. So yes, a point belonging to an area does make more sense. You can still refer to $EP1$, but in the context of some vector metric.

Comment: @ArtificialBreeze yes, you've understood it right. I've discussed this a bit with my friends and got the idea of defining the "area" as a set, $A_{E} = 
\begin{Bmatrix}
      A_{xE} : & -\frac{l}{2} &\leq & A_{xE} &\leq & \frac{l}{2} \\
   A_{yE} : &  -\frac{w}{2} &\leq &A_{yE} &\leq & \frac{w}{2}
\end{Bmatrix} $. where $A_{xE}$ and $A_{yE}$ are the restrictions in x and y axis. Instead of defining $EP1$ as a vector it is referred to as a point, i.e. if we move the coordinate frame to $E$, $EP1$ will be the coordinate of $P1$ in the new coordinate frame ($E$ will have coordinate 0,0).

Comment: Then we will check if the point EP1 belongs to the set $A_E$. Do you think that this a good approach?

Comment: This sounds interesting, fixing $E$ as being your reference frame is good since you can basically ignore it and work on $P1$ (intuitively it is equivalent to moving your distance vector to the origin, I guess). I am really interested in how your simulation will go, feel free to continue posting updates here or in separate questions.